# Python: substitute escaping character in exsisting string

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, suppose there is an existing str `pattern` in following format,

```
pattern = r"\t Hello World!\n"
```

I want to substitute `{r'\','t'}` to tab character `'\t'`, `{r'\', '\n'}` to newline character `'\n'` (and also other possible escape character). In other word, I want to get `new_pattern` in following format from `pattern`:

```
new_pattern = "\t Hello World!\n"
```

I can substitute them one by one:

```
new_pattern = re.sub(r'\t', '\t', pattern)
new_pattern = re.sub(r'\n', '\n', new_pattern)
...
```

or

```
new_pattern = re.sub(r'\\t', '\t', pattern)
new_pattern = re.sub(r'\\n', '\n', new_pattern)
...
```

But this is a little tedious, since there are many possible escape characters.
Is there any common way to "re-interpret" a str? (I don't know what should we call this kind of situation.)

Comment: Why do you have that string in the first place? Does that come from some wrong code that should be fixed instead?

Comment: @KellyBundy, it is input, from command line or from a function parameter. This is a duplicated question. But I think it is hard to describle it.